# cygbin: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: cygwin, hbase

Installing **hadoop1.0.3** successfully. Now run Hbase service(start-hbase.sh command) 
Having changes in **hbaseenv.sh** and **hbasesite.xml**

**But the problem arises:**

[image]

Please suggest how to resolve this problem and aslo **cygpath: can't convert empty path**

Comment: Start by isolating the bad line hbase by placing some echo commands there

Comment: Can you provide JRE or JDK version?